# How to make image in same msg

Tags: discord.py

I have a hug command in my Discord.py bot where it randomizes a picture to send, however, it sends the text and picture in different messages I don't understand why it does this

original code

```
await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} hugged {member.mention}")``{ctx.author.mention} hugged {member.mention}")
 await ctx.send(random.choice(hugs))`
```

I tried to integrate them both together but it sends a link as well like this `await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.display_name} hugged {member.mention}\n{random.choice(hugs)}")` but after it shows the link, does anyone know how to put them both in the same message without the link?

Comment: There isn't any link in your code. What link are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Instead for this case, you can send an embed with the image and text contained within it.

Here is an example applying it to your command, also make sure you have the rest of your variables defined. This can now get a random image from your `hugs` array and display it within the embed below the content, as well as the text you want to include in it.

```py
@client.command()
async def hug(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
        if member == None:
                await ctx.send('Mention someone to hug')
                return
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{ctx.author.name} hugged {member}')
        embed.set_image(url=random.choice(hugs))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```